# implied eval is evil. pass a function instead of string. missing semicolon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

implied eval is evil. pass a function instead of string. missing semicolon give error i want to show live time in text filed but what problem with code first line anyone can solve it?

```js
window.onload = function(){ getSuccessOutput(); setInterval( "getSuccessOutput()", 1000);$("sd").css('display','none');}

function getSuccessOutput() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://185.27.134.9/htdocs/panel/timestamp.php',
        complete: function (response) {
            $('#time').val(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#time').val('Bummer: there was an error!');
        },

    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML code as well please? We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

These are all linter warnings, not Javascript errors.

Your linter is complaining that you're passing a *string* to `setInterval`, which can be, as said, as bad as `eval`. Pass the plain function name instead:

```
setInterval(getSuccessOutput, 1000);
```

Also, the "missing semicolon" warning is from the `window.onload` assignment - all assignments should have semicolons at the end, so put one after the final `}` of the `function(){` block:

```
window.onload = function() {
  getSuccessOutput();
  setInterval(getSuccessOutput, 1000);
  $("sd").css('display', 'none');
};
//^
```